# Error 403 when using Graph API to post a message on a feed:

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to post a message using the [Graph API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Graph_API) and a C++ program. I have tried three different methods:

> 1. GET with a URL like `https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/feed?access_token=TOKEN&message=Hello`
> 2. POST and X-WWW_FORM
> 3. POST and FORM-data

In the case 1, I receive the complete list of messages as an answer, but the message doesn't add to the feed.

In the case 2 and 3, I receive an error **403** as the response.

`USER_ID` and `TOKEN` are correct and my application has the right permissions. I have reached posting an image to an album with the same application, but it's impossible for me right now to publish messages. Why?

Comment: From where we can get user_id for our app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first method won't work because you need to issue an HTTP POST to that endpoint to publish a new feed story, as a commodity facebook provides the "method=post" GET parameter to "fake" a post, this will work

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/feed?access_token=TOKEN&message=Hello&method=post
```

and as response you'll get the id of the new post

```
{
   "id": "499801468_1001264776039"
}
```

Here you can find more details on publishing with the Graph API http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#publishing

Comment: I recieve this answer from facebook:
{
   "error": {
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "message": "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"
   }
}

With the same acces_token that I use to upload photos and I have the "publish_stream" permissions [link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/)

Comment: Verify that you definitely do have the publish stream permission by calling '/me/permissions' in the Graph API. Also check that the user whose wall you're posting on doesn't have privacy settings which prevent the user your access token is for posting on their wall

Comment: Thanks @Igy, I had a wrong permission tag, and recieve an auth error, but the session begins with the old permissions that my app had

Comment: @Agusti I am getting 403 error. can you tell me what is User Id that we need to pass? I am using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38829622/posting-on-facebook-via-unificationengine to post messages.

Comment: @lgy can you please answer this question -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41544642/forbidden-error-403-in-unification-engine-api-while-sending-message. I have checked everything you have mentioned in your comment.