# Posting on facebook via unificationengine

Tags: unificationengine

Hi I'd like to post to facebook via unification engine. I've already created a user, added and tested successfully a facebook connection, but when I post I get the following response:

`{"Status":{"facebook":{"status":190,"info":"Error validating access token: Session does not match current stored session. This may be because the user changed the password since the time the session was created or Facebook has changed the session for security reasons.: "}},"URIs":[]}`

When I use the facebook token, that was used for creating the connection, to post to facebook directly (without `unificationengine`), then it works just fine. What might be the problem here? Status 190 is neither documented on facebook nor on `unificationengine`.

**@unificatinengine developers:** it would be practical, if the errors returned by the service would be passed on inside the `unificationengine` response, this way debugging such errors would be easier, and the errors could also be processed programmatically.

**Additional info**
Today I seem not to be able to reproduce the response of yesterday. The postfields I use to post the message to facebook (the same as yesterday) are as follows:
`{
    "message":{
        "receivers":[
            {
                "name":"me",
                "address":"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/me/feed",
                "Connector":"facebook"
            }
        ],
        "sender":{
            "address":"sender address"
        },
        "subject":"test",
        "parts":[
            {
                "id":"0",
                "contentType":"text/plain",
                "type":"body",
                "size":25,
                "data":"this is the plain message"
            },
            {
                "id":"1",
                "contentType":"text/html",
                "type":"body",
                "size":42,
                "data":"<div>this is the <b>html</b> message</div>"
            },
            {
                "id":"2",
                "contentType":"text/plain",
                "type":"link",
                "size":17,
                "data":"http://www.web.de"
            },
            {
                "id":"3",
                "contentType":"text/plain",
                "type":"link_description",
                "size":21,
                "data":"some link description"
            },
            {
                "id":"4",
                "contentType":"text/plain",
                "type":"link_title",
                "size":10,
                "data":"link title"
            }
        ]
    }
}`
But today I get the following message back from `unificationengine`
`{
    "Status":{
        "facebook":{
            "status":100,
            "info":"Unsupported post request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api: "
        }
    },
  "URIs":[]
}`
Unfortunately this does not tell me, what `unificationengine` does internally for posting to facebook (which should not concern me), and what goes wrong there.

Comment: what do we need to send in address parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the "/v2/connection/info" show the details of the facebook connection that you have added? If not can you please update the connection with a new access token, using the same connection identifier for the "v2/connection/add" api endpoint, and check if it works.

```
unificationengine
```

Comment: "/v2/connection/info" does work and gives me the some basic info about my user on facebook, but posts are still not possible, although with another error message today (see **Additional info** above)

Comment: Can you please change  "name":"me", to "name":"**Me**"  in receivers part and try

Comment: I am getting 403 forbidden error. Followed same steps as yours. All other curl requests working fine except send message.